# Navigating to new UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to the world of iOS and I'm trying to build a simple app in Swift. I have a navigation controller linked to a LoginViewController (the login screen). The login screen has a button linked to a RegisterViewController. From the login screen the user can press the "Register" button and be taken to the register screen with the back functionality in the top left corner (ie: be taken back to the login screen).

The login screen also has a "Log In" button hooked up in the LoginViewController as follows:

```
@IBAction func LoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let welcome = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("welcome") as HomePageViewController;

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(welcome, animated: true);
    }
```

This takes the user to the welcome screen which has a class of `HomePageViewController` and a `Storyboard ID` of `welcome`. My problem right now is that once the user reaches the welcome screen, the navigation bars has a `< Login` on the left. Similarly, if the Welcome screen is reached through the Register screen the top left nav has `< Back`.

What I'd like to do is "separate" the welcome screen and anything after it from the login and register screens. How can I do this?

Here's how my `Main.storyboard` looks right now:

[image: Main.storyboard]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use modalViewController to present rather than pushing it into a navigationController stack.

So to present welcome:

```
self.presentViewController(welcome, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Then when you try to dismiss, call this in your `welcomeController` which you want to dismiss.

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```